# C# - Recommended SDK/Toolkit(s) For Drawing Tournament Bracket

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, tournament

I would like to develop a UI for creating/displaying single elimination brackets in C#. The only problem is, I am not a UI developer and I don't really know if there is a particular SDK/Toolkit/App/etc. that is the most supported for use. The application will not be web based to start. I am however an experienced developer so the back-end programming will not be an issue nor should it be the focus of this post.

I have looked into Adobe Air, Flex, WPF, and Silverlight as those are just a few different tools that came to mind that could be of use. Are there any particular toolkits or SDKs that are preferred for drawing out the necessary labels and brackets?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think the best answer is completely dependent on if this is WinForms, WPF, WebForms, MVC, etc.

Comment: Then add a winforms tag (if you want assistance).

Answer (score 1):

The first question is whether there will be any input through this surface, for example if the team/player names will be editable/clickable. In that case you probably want to use controls as well as some custom drawing of the brackets.

If you only want to draw a representation that is not editable, then I would recommend drawing the whole thing yourself on a panel.